# Code chunk font size in Rmarkdown with knitr and latex

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

In knitr, the size option works fine in a `.Rnw` file, the following code generates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<chunk1, size="huge">>=
summary(mtcars)
@


\end{document}
```

[image: rnw]

However, I can't get it to work in Rmarkdown. The following code does not change the font size, as it did in `.rnw` file. The same thing happens when trying to set options with `opts_chunk$set(size="huge")`.

Is this the expected behavior? How does one change the chunk code font size? (I mean using knitr options, not by adding `\huge` before the code)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, size="huge"}
summary(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

I am using RStudio Version 0.98.987, knitr 1.6 and rmarkdown 0.2.68.

Comment: Unfortunately the `size` option only works for Rnw. For R Markdown (v2), I think the only way is to redefine the code environments for Pandoc/LaTeX (see the section "Includes" at http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html).

Comment: Personally I'd rather redefine environments in LaTeX instead of using hooks, because the latter approach may not be portable, e.g. you may use a chunk hook to add `\begin{huge}` and `\end{huge}` around a chunk, but then you will be stuck in LaTeX unless you do not want other document formats such as HTML, Word, ... A side comment: tweaking styles is like this kitten bothering you: http://i.imgur.com/17B4U.gif It is tempting to tweak the style while you work, and it is very distractive and endless work as well :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Picking up the idea to alter a knitr hook we can do the following:

```
def.chunk.hook  <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("chunk")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  x <- def.chunk.hook(x, options)
  ifelse(options$size != "normalsize", paste0("\n \\", options$size,"\n\n", x, "\n\n \\normalsize"), x)
})
```

This snippet modifies the default chunk hook. It simply checks if the chunk option size is not equal to its default (`normalsize`) and if so, prepends the value of `options$size` to the output of the code chunk (including the source!) and appends `\\normalsize` in order to switch back.

So if you would add `size="tiny"` to a chunk, then all the output generated by this chunk will be printed that way.

All you have to do is to include this snippet at the beginning of your document.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer: Afaik, your answer works for LaTex output only. Would you know of any handy solution which works for both HTML and LaTex?

Comment: Great answer indeed. It worked flawlessly on my local machine but failed on a server. Solution on the server was to add an extra `\n` as discribed by YihuI [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1296#issuecomment-252754095). I have made an edit to the answer to include this.

Comment: This is a great answer indeed if you want to a) have a LaTeX file with a lot of `\small` and `\normalsize` switches along the whole document, and b) if you want EVERY chunk to have the same size. 

I am using [Bookdown's example environments](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#tab:theorem-envs) and I don't want those to be `\small`. It's possible to setup this "by type of chunk" in some way?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323331/code-chunk-font-size-in-beamer-with-knitr-and-latex), redefining the aspect of the environment is better for LaTeX, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446905/rmarkdown-font-size-and-header), specifying it using CSS, is better for html output.

Comment: This typically works well, but I've found that it makes it so that code chunks can't be included in incremental lists ( [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538154/uncover-code-chunk-in-rmarkdown-and-beamer](here's an IOSlides example of an incremental list) )

Answer (score 29):

````
\tiny

```{r}
summary(mtcars)
```
\normalsize
````

available options for size in descending order are:
`Huge` > `huge` > `LARGE` > `Large` > `large` > `normalsize` > `small` > `footnotesize` > `scriptsize` > `tiny`

Comment: This obliterated the use of figure references for me.

Answer (score 18):

Per [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Pakillo/8b46a48ea806572566d9#file-rmarkdown-fontsize-rmd), you have to define the font size using css:

```
<style type="text/css">
body, td {
   font-size: 14px;
}
code.r{
  font-size: 20px;
}
pre {
  font-size: 20px
}
</style>
```

`code.r` will control the font size for R code echoed from the code chunk, while `pre` will apply to any R results output from the code.

A complete working .Rmd file might look like:

````
---
title: "FontTest"
author: "Thomas Hopper"
date: "January 13,2016"
output: html_document
---

<style type="text/css">

body, td {
   font-size: 14px;
}
code.r{
  font-size: 20px;
}
pre {
  font-size: 20px
}
</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

The resulting html renders as:

[image: screenshot showing 20pt R code and 20pt R output]

Comment: I believe that the original poster asks for font size change in pdf output, while your example changes the font size for html output.

Comment: However, trying to google a solution to change font size in html output I ended here. Therefore, the answer is useful - although it wasn't for the OP.

Comment: @Tom: very useful, but when I try it I find that 'per' applies to both code and R output, with 'code.r' being unresponsive. Also, is there a way of doing this for a specific chunk?

Answer (score 9):

You can define you own document format by exporting something based on the following function from your package `my_package`:

```
my_report <- function(...) {

  fmt <- rmarkdown::pdf_document(...)

  fmt$knitr$knit_hooks$size = function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before) return(paste0("\n \\", options$size, "\n\n"))
    else return("\n\n \\normalsize \n")
  }

  return(fmt)
}
```

This will define a knitr chunk hook `size` that will put the appropriate latex command before the chunk, and `\normalsize` after the chunk.

Anyway, with the following R markdown you can check if it's working:

````
---
output: my_package::my_report
---

Test text for comparison

```{r}
print(1)
```
The next code chunk has `size = 'tiny'` in the chunk options.

```{r, size = 'tiny'}
print(1)
```
````

I get the following result from `markdown::render():

[image]

See also the issue I opened on github:

https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1296

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @Martin Schmelzer's output, here's a solution in the case you want to change the code and output default font size **for the whole document**, but not the size of the text.

```r
def.chunk.hook  <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("chunk")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  x <- def.chunk.hook(x, options)
  paste0("\n \\", "size_of_the_code_and_output","\n\n", x, "\n\n \\size_of_the_text")
})
```

For instance,

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
def.chunk.hook  <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("chunk")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  x <- def.chunk.hook(x, options)
  paste0("\n \\", "footnotesize","\n\n", x, "\n\n \\Huge")
})
```

# Section 1
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
Text.

# Section 2
```{r}
print(1)
```
This works for every chunks.
````

gives this:
[image: Example]

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered! Thanks.