# `bookdown`/`rmarkdown`/`knitr`: Line wrapping in code chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pdflatex, bookdown

I'm using

````
```{r}
library(magrittr)
session_info <- devtools::session_info(include_base = TRUE)
session_info[[2]] <- session_info %>%
  magrittr::extract2(2) %>%
  magrittr::inset2("date", value = NULL)
session_info
```
````

at the end of my `bookdown` document. As I am using `git` tracked in-house packages the version strings get a bit longer. This results in `R`/`knitr`/`rmarkdown`/`bookdown` line-breaking the resulting `data.frame` (`session_info[[2]]`), which disconnects names and versions visually and is thus suboptimal.

I have played with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526740/2103880) solution to reduce code chunk font size, but that just renders it clear that the root of the problem is line breaking happening somewhere prior to `pdflatex`ing.

Where could I influence when `R`/`knitr`/`rmarkdown`/`bookdown` line-breaks code output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final `session_info` call transparently invokes `print` on the object (through `print.data.frame` in the case of `session_info[[2]]`).

`print` offers a `width` argument, which defaults to `getOption("width")` and for which `?options` states

> `width`:
>
> controls the maximum number of columns on a line used in printing vectors, matrices and arrays, and when filling by cat.
>
> Columns are normally the same as characters except in East Asian languages.

Accordingly and as `getOption("width")` produces 136 in my environment, above code may be augmented to:

````
```{r}
library(magrittr)
session_info <- devtools::session_info(include_base = TRUE)
session_info[[2]] <- session_info %>%
  magrittr::extract2(2) %>%
  magrittr::inset2("date", value = NULL)
print(session_info, width = 200)
```
````