# How can I control fontsize and linestretch of code chunks independently from the main text in bookdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

Using `bookdown` to output a .pdf document the YAML within the `index.Rmd` looks like this currently:

```
--- 
title: "My title"
author:
  - 'me'

output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    includes:
      in_header: latex/preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes

site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
geometry: "left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
bibliography: [packages.bib, referencias.bib]
linkcolor: NavyBlue
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
toc-depth: 2
lof: True
lot: True
---
```

How can I control `fontsize` and `linestretch` of code chunks independently from the main text? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646333/code-chunk-font-size-in-rmarkdown-with-knitr-and-latex) provides a solution to control font size, but not line spacing.

Comment: What you wanna alter? line spacing in source code or e.g. row spacing in tables?

Comment: I want to change the line spacing of code chunks, like some of the "code decoration" features available for code chunks: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-decoration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's is the same idea as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526740/1777111) but now we just alter the source hook:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
def.source.hook  <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("source")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  x <- def.source.hook(x, options)  # apply default source hook
  ifelse(!is.null(options$linestretch),  # if linestretch is not NULL, apply linestretch
         paste0("\\linespread{", options$linestretch,"}\n", x, "\n\n\\linespread{1}"),  # reset linestretch after the chunk!
         x)
})
```
````

Now you can copy and paste the `ifelse` statement from the other answer into this hook as well and you can control both.

Full example:

````
---
title: "Linestretch"
date: "20 December 2018"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    keep_tex: true
linestretch: "`r (lstr <- 1.5)`" 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = F)
def.source.hook  <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("source")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  x <- def.source.hook(x, options)
  x <- ifelse(!is.null(options$linestretch), 
              paste0("\\linespread{", options$linestretch,"}\n", x, "\n\n\\linespread{", lstr,"}"), 
              x)
  ifelse(!is.null(options$size), 
         paste0("\\", options$size,"\n\n", x, "\n\n \\normalsize"), 
         x)
})
```

## R Markdown

\lipsum[30]


```{r, linestretch = 1, size="Large"}
head(mtcars)
head(mtcars)
```


\lipsum[30]
````

[image]

Comment: Your proposed solution works well for chunks. However, `linestretch` in the main text after the first code chunk is also changed, instead of following the global `linestretch` provided in the YAML.

Comment: That is because in the hook we reset the linestretch after the source code to 1. If you change that number to tho global linestretch everything is fine.

Comment: I altered the answer so that you define the global linestretch as a R variable which is used in the hook as well.

Comment: I can't make this work with linestretch within a `knitr::kable()`. Oddly enough, `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{x}` does not work for me either! Any fixes to specific chunks with table ?