# Uncover code chunk in Rmarkdown and beamer

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

is it possible to reveal code chunks when using beamer and Rmarkdown? The following gives an error because of the `#` around the output, I think.

````
---
title: "test"
output: beamer_presentation
---

# Test Reveal
Text

\visible<2->{
Code
```{r}
print(2 + 2)
```
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a very similar effect by using a `\pause` before your code block:

````
---
title: "test"
output: beamer_presentation
---

# Test Reveal
Text

\pause
Code
```{r}
print(2 + 2)
```
````