# Remove line break in Markdown output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to print the content of a `data.table` to a Markdown document out of R-Studio. However, the ouput is somewhat wider, so I decreased the font, as described here: [Code chunk font size in Rmarkdown with knitr and latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646333/code-chunk-font-size-in-rmarkdown-with-knitr-and-latex)

However, even when decreasing the font to tiny, the line break remains although there is plenty of space to have the columns adjacent. I wonder how this can be achieved.

````
---
title: "mwe"
output: pdf_document
---

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(id=1:5,num=31:35,text=c("a","b","c","d","here you can find some long text to artificially widen this text column and demonstrate the problem"))
```
Here is some text.

\tiny
```{r}
dat

```
````

[image: output2]dat[5]

Comment: What is your question? Do you want all the columns in the same rows? I don't understand what is your desired output.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Clarified.

Comment: Why are you adding the "here you can find some long text to artificially widen this text column and demonstrate the problem"? I guess I don't understand why you are adding extra text just to show a problem, unless you can show a real use case when it's actually a problem.

Comment: This is an example. My real problem has a column with text that long and I would like to print it.

Comment: okay, thank you. Maybe you could just make another output specifically for this observation with it's text.

Comment: I have done so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `?options` and look for the parameter `width` that controls the number of columns printed per line:

````
---
title: "mwe"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(id=1:5,num=31:35,text=c("a","b","c","d","here you can find some long text to artificially widen this text column and demonstrate the problem"))
```

\tiny
```{r}
dat
```

```{r}
options(width = 120)
dat
```
````

[image]