# papaja: Changing font sizes and faces for code listings and R output

Tags: r-markdown, papaja

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165918/adding-preamble-tex-and-or-modifying-css), I was able to get 2-column papaja with listings wrapping (rather than overflowing column width). But the listings package turns off various features that help code listings and R output stand out relative to the main text.

A simple solution would be if I could globally change the font faces and/or sizes selectively for code and R output. Is there a way to do that in papaja? I haven't been able to figure this out from papaja or Rmarkdown documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the listings package in a **papaja** (or **bookdown**) document, what is technically happening is that all code is wrapped into an `lstlisting` LaTeX environment that comes with its own capabilities of customizing code appearance. Hence, you don't see the syntax highlighting that you would otherwise see if you would not use the `listings` package. The documentation of the listings package with instructions how to style your code [can be found here](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings).

To make use of this, you can extend the YAML header of your papaja document like this:

```
documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "jou"
output            :
  papaja::apa6_pdf:
    pandoc_args: --listings
header-includes:
  - \lstset{breaklines=true,language=R,basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,frame=trB,commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\textit}
```

Here, I first specify the code's language, and use a tiny monospace font. With `frame`, I add a frame around the code block, and with `commentstyle` I set comments in italic and gray.

Comment: Perfect -- thank you so much. The 'frame=trB' led to latex overflow errors, but with that removed (and the commentstyle, too) this gave me exactly the kind of output the typesetting staff at the journal wanted. THANK YOU.