# How to change r chunk font size of Rmarkdown project?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

This is my current setup:

```
---
title: "Project"
output: rmdformats::material
---
<style>
body{
  font-size: 10pt;
}
</style>
```

I would like to make r chunks even smaller in size than the font of the rest of the document. How can I achieve this?

This doesn't work:

```
{r, size="small"}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646333/code-chunk-font-size-in-rmarkdown-with-knitr-and-latex) didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own CSS classes to R chunks using the following syntax:

````
```{r class.source = "small"}

print("Hello World")

```
````

Presume the `small` class name will give you the desired Material effect.